# String("2013-4-25") to date conversion

Tags: java, string, date, format

I have a String like 
`"2013-4-25"` 
I need to convert this into `"MM-dd-yyyy"` format. Later I will have to append this `date` like

```
Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
```

How could I do this?

Comment: which language are you using , btw ?

Comment: Java. Edited the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
String str = "2013-4-25";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat parseFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Date date = parseFormatter.parse(str);

            String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.println(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`. Check this link : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm

You can specify formatter of your choice ans then format date accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JodaTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) and the [`DateMidnight`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) class, and you won't have to normalize the date yourself. Something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.fromPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateMidnight date = DateMidnight.parse(date, format);
```

The `Calendar` and `Date` APIs in the JDK is a pain...